# docker起動時に一部のコンテナが自動で起動するのを止めたい

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-composeに`restart: always`が記述されていないのにdocker起動時に自動で起動しようとする設定を止めたいです。ただどこで設定されているか分からなくて困っています。 dockerアプリ自体にそのような設定する項目等があるのでしょうか。
そして全てのcomposeに書いたコンテナが起動するのではなくその内一部のみです。

以下のコマンドで自動起動の設定になってるコンテナを検索してみたのですが、何も出力されませんでした。

```
docker inspect -f "{{.Name}} {{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}}" $(docker ps -aq) | grep always
```

質問しておきながら大変申し訳ないのですが、docker-composeのファイル自体は会社の物なので載せれないです。
もしそれ以外で不足している情報やこれが記述されているのでは等ありましたら宜しくお願い致します。

追記
`restart: on-failure` という記述を発見しました。こちらは正常終了の場合は再起動がかからない設定だと思われるのですが、 `ctrl+c` ではなく `docker-compose down` 場合のみに適用されるのでしょうか？

Comment: まっさらな環境を用意して、問題となっているイメージたちの中からひとつ選んで持ってきた場合でも問題が再現しますでしょうか。再現する場合、その docker-compose.yml を機密が含まれない状態に書き換えることで質問文に載せることは可能でしょうか。再現しない場合、docker の外側の設定で docker 自体の起動とは関係なく起動している可能性はないでしょうか。たとえば systemd で起動されている場合などです。

Comment: 「自動起動するもの/しないもの」の差分を確認してみてください。また、「会社の」ということはあなた以外が何か操作等を行っている可能性はありますか？

Comment: `restart: on-failure`  という記述を見つけました。これが原因な気がします。

Comment: `systemd` を使ってコンテナの自動起動ができるのですね
知りませんでした。新しい用語と視点をありがとうございます。

Comment: 差分を見るのはとても大事だと思いました。ありがとうございます！